Why won't @Value.Immutable generate code if in test package?
@Value.Immutable 
public interface Foobar {
List<Integer> getStuff(); 
// additional getter methods for custom objects 
}

I am surprised to find the above code snippet when the file/package path is in src/main/java will generate code as expected. However when it is in src/test/java it doesn't generate any code. I haven't been able to find an answer to why yet.
I build through gradle ./gradlew assemble
build.gradle contains
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor(libs.immutables.value)
  implementation(libs.immutables.value)
  implementation(libs.immutables.annotate)
  testAnnotationProcessor(libs.immutables.value)
  testImplementation(libs.immutables.value)
  testImplementation(libs.immutables.annotate)
}


How do you build your code? Maven/Gradle/by hand?

Sorry about that, updated, build through gradle

annotationProcessor and implementation will only apply to your application code, not to your test code. Add testAnnotationProcessor and testImplementation to change that:
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor(libs.immutables.value)
  implementation(libs.immutables.value)
  implementation(libs.immutables.annotate)
  testAnnotationProcessor(libs.immutables.value)
  testImplementation(libs.immutables.value)
  testImplementation(libs.immutables.annotate)
}


I've added this to question for what is being currently attempted, unfortunately I'm still not getting the autogenerated code
